# Specifying bbl in Latex2rtf using Lyx

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, latex2rtf

I'm trying to export a Lyx-file (lyx) to a RTF-file with [Latex2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/manpage.html) using Lyx.

I've already generated a bbl-file by writing following commands in the Terminal:

```
latex file.tex
bibtex file.aux
```

I've tried to edit the "Extra flag"-setting to '-b' in Preferences>File handling>Converters menu (highlighting LaTeX (plain) -> Rich Text Format). But also the converter field itself:

```
latex2rtf -b $$i
```

My desired output is to display the citations correctly in my RTF file.

To use the latex2rtf command is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: What operating system are you running? Under Windows, LaTeX2RTF provides functionality to include a `.bbl` as far as I can see, so it's not something LyX should be concerned about.